# How to get logs in vscode debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to make vscode's extension which can get log in debug console and make suggestions for errors, but i dont know how to get the log, So my question is if have some documentation to manipulate debug console messages or how i can work with debug console messages in my vscode extension.

Comment: I'm interested in this too. The only solution might be to dig into the source of VS Code. I found this commit where they were changing how the debug console was named, which may be a good starting point: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/5245/files 
I will update here if I get time to research further.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?